# How to set a foreign key which is dependent on the relation of other two tables?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship

I have 3 tables; teachers table, subjects table and events table.
1.There is one to many relationship between subjects and teachers, that is each teacher can teach only one subject but, many teachers can teach same subjects.
2.There is a many to many relationship between teachers and events.

### Example of subjects table

```
id(PK)      |  name
-------------------
1           |  php
-------------------
2           |  java
-------------------
3           |  python
-------------------
4           |  c++
--------------------
5           |  c#
```

### Example of teachers table

```
id(PK)      |  name      | subject_id(FK to subjects.id) 
----------------------------------
1           |  messi     |  2
----------------------------------
2           |  ronaldo   |  4
----------------------------------
3           |  pele      |  1
----------------------------------
4           |  maradona  |  2
```

### Example of events table

```
id(PK)      |  venue      | subject_id (FK to teacher.id)     | teacher_id(FK to subject.id)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1           |  location1  |       2                           |      has to be either 1 or 4
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2           |  location2  |       1                           |      has to be 3 only
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3           |  location3  |       4                           |      has to be 2 only
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4           |  location4  |       4                           |      has to be 2 only
```

How do i get a `foreign key` drop down menu in `teacher_id` field with available options based on assigned value in `subject_id`? if not possible atleast an error message after clicking `go` in data insert section in `phpmyadmin`?

Comment: What is the reason of downvoting?

Comment: @philipxy `This` is giving `page not found`.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

I don't use phpmyadmin, but I'd start with

- a unique constraint on subjects.name,
- a unique constraint on the pair {teachers.name, teachers.subject_id},
- a unique constraint on {events.venue, events.subject_id, events.teacher_id},
- a unique constraint on the pair {teachers.id, teachers.subject_id}.

The first three have to do with identity; the last one lets you target {teachers.id, teachers.subject_id} with a foreign key constraint.

In the general case, people's names aren't unique. So you *could* have two teachers with the same name who teach the same subject. How you might approach that kind of problem is application-dependent.

Then foreign keys

- from teachers.subject_id to subjects.id, and
- from {events.teacher_id, events.subject_id} to {teachers.id, teachers.subject_id}

That will at least give you an error if you try to insert into events a teacher with the wrong subject.

You need to [use the INNODB engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html) to enforce foreign key constraints. Other engines will parse them, but ignore them.

> The FOREIGN KEY and REFERENCES clauses are supported by the InnoDB
>   storage engine, which implements ADD [CONSTRAINT [symbol]] FOREIGN KEY
>   [index_name] (...) REFERENCES ... (...). See Section 14.6.6, “InnoDB
>   and FOREIGN KEY Constraints”. For other storage engines, the clauses
>   are parsed but ignored.

Comment: please provide the full mysql code to solve the problem , it will really help.

Comment: yes i'm using INNODB engine, just provide the mysql code please to create events table, so that subject_id, teacher_id pair in the events table obeys the teachers table.

Comment: "Write my code for me" doesn't work well on StackOverflow. Since you now know what you need to do, you can try your hardest, and if you fail, ask another question. If you do ask another question, make sure it includes your code, your database version, and any error messages.

Comment: after some research i found we can't even set a `check` in mysql , we need to use trigger. so basically i didn't get an answer and meanwhile someone downvoted my question without any reason.

Comment: MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints, but if you use the innodb engine, it will enforce foreign key constraints. You don't need triggers for this.